# ANT - Converting a String to Path with location attribute

Tags: ant, location, classpath, pathelement

I have the following ANT script that gives me a list of websphere libraries at runtime based on the websphere root directory.  I need to convert the resulting string into separate path location elements

My current script is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TestPath" basedir="." default="print-dirset">

    <target name="init" description="Define websphere libraries">
        <property name="compile.lib.dir" value="C:\Software\WAS85" />
    </target>
    <target name="print-dirset" depends="init" description="">
        <path id="websphere.libs">
            <dirset dir="${compile.lib.dir}">
                <include name="*" />
            </dirset>
        </path>
        <property name="websphere.libs.list" refid="websphere.libs" />
        <echo message="websphere.libs.list: ${websphere.libs.list}" />
        <pathconvert property="websphere.libs.convert" pathsep="${file.separator}*${path.separator}">
            <path path="${websphere.libs.list}" />
        </pathconvert>
        <echo message="websphere.libs.convert: ${websphere.libs.convert}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

which outputs a string like below

```
 [echo] websphere.libs.list: C:\Software\WAS85\Scheduler;C:\Software\WAS85\UDDIReg;C:\Software\WAS85\bin;C:\Software\WAS85\configuration;....C:\Software\WAS85\web;C:\Software\WAS85\wlp
 [echo] websphere.libs.convert: C:\Software\WAS85\Scheduler\*;C:\Software\WAS85\UDDIReg\*;C:\Software\WAS85\bin\*;C:\Software\WAS85\configuration\*;...C:\Software\WAS85\web\*;C:\Software\WAS85\wlp
```

I would like to translate the second string above into a structure like below

```
<path id="websphere.classpath">
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\Scheduler\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\UDDIReg\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\bin\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\configuration\*" />
......
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\web\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\wlp\*" />
</path>
```

The last element in the conversion also needs to add the '\*' part which is not in the original string.

which can then be used with a structure like

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
  <path refid="ext.classpath"/>
  <path refid="websphere.classpath"/>
  <path refid="module.compile.classpath"/>
</path>
```

The purpose of the above attempt is to reduce the length of classpath by using wildcard classpath provided by JDK 1.6 and which is available in ANT starting ANT 1.8.2.  I am using ANT 1.8.4.

I am not an expert in ANT, I can just get by, by looking at examples.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?  How can I do it?  Any example would be very helpful.

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve what I want to do?  I have explained why I do not want to use the fileset answer that is given.  It does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Please send me a message if you found the solution to this! I face the same problems as you.

Comment: To verify that the wildcard classpath construct actually works, I also tried to do it from commandline in Windows 7 and linux.  In both tests, it worked from commandline.  

I also 'hardcoded' the classpath in the build script.  And in both cases - Windows and linux - it doesn't work from ANT script.  So, it seems, even though the documentation says it should work for ANT 1.8.2 or later, it doesn't appear to.

Comment: @Daniel - I have answered the wildcard part of the question, but do not know how to send a message to user.  Hope you get the answer by coming to this question

Comment: Thank you, I already found a solution by just using wildcards. Thanks for trying to notify me!

Comment: @Daniel Would you mind sharing your solution by using just wildcards without using the fork and executable attributes?

Comment: Sorry, I use fork and pass the classpath by wildcard expression to the JVM now. Need a later Ant 1.8.x AFAIK.

Comment: ok, thanks.  So, i don't need to use the executable, just fork is enough, it seems.

BTW, the minimum version of ANT required for wildcard is 1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the wildcard part to work by using the fork="yes" and executable="path-to-my-executable" attributes in the javac task.

I do not want to mark the question answered, because my basic question was about converting the string.  But since the answer received didn't talk about that and also didn't mention how to get wildcard classpath working, and the purpose of my question was to get the wildcard classpath working, i have noted it here for whoever is trying to get that to work

I still need some help in converting the semi-colon separated string to construct like below

```
<path id="websphere.classpath">
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\Scheduler\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\UDDIReg\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\bin\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\configuration\*" />
......
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\web\*" />
    <pathelement location="C:\Software\WAS85\wlp\*" />
</path>
```

**Update:**

I wrote a custom ANT task to get the wildcard classpath working

Answer (score 0):

If all of your dependencies reside in `C:\Software\WAS85`, you can use [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) to catch all of your dependencies:

```
<fileset dir="${compile.lib.dir}" id="compile.files">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <!-- include name="**/*.jar" /-->
</fileset>
```

You can then use to refer to this fileset as `compile.files` elsewhere in your `build.xml`.

Comment: The problem with using fileset as in the above construct is that it will list all the jars in one directory. It will also not give me list of directories under a given path.  I want to use the wildcard classpath as indicated in my question.  This does not let me do that.

Comment: With the method I outlined above, you can pull in all `.java` files in that directory and subdirectories too. If you're trying to build a set of classpath locations, you can use `classpathref` task. Note that [classpathref](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)  can contain directories and files too.

Comment: I think you have not understood my question fully.  If you read my question, I have outlined what I have and what I am trying to achieve.  I do not want to use the .java files.  The root directory contains directories that contain jar files which need to be added to classpath. I do not want to add each of those jar files, I want to add them as wildcards

Comment: Your wildcard syntax usage is not going to reduce the length of your classpath. There are two attributes to `<pathelement>` here. If you specify `location` attribute, you're pointing to a file. OTOH, if you specify `path` attribute, you specify that directory. On the whole, adding a directory to classpath is same as adding a list of jar files in that directory. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Of course it will. If I list the jars in the directory, it will be much longer that listing it with a '*'. Please take a look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html - it has the below comment

Since Ant 1.8.2 the location attribute can also contain a wildcard in its last path component (i.e. it can end in a "*") in order to support wildcard CLASSPATHs introduced with Java6. Ant will not expand or evaluate the wildcards and the resulting path may not work as anything else but a CLASSPATH - or even as a CLASSPATH for a Java VM prior to Java6.