# How to run/debug ANT from inside RAD / Eclipse

Tags: ant, installation, rad, launcher

In order to do more research / debugging related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141657/ant-converting-a-string-to-path-with-location-attribute) question, I am trying to debug ANT from within RAD. I have downloaded ANT source and compiled ANT.  I want to start my compiled version as an ANT java program from within RAD to enable me to debug.  I looked at these links - 1. [Launch multiple java programs from RAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316761/how-to-launch-multiple-java-programs-with-one-configuration-on-separate-consoles) and 2. [Setting up ANT launcher in RAD](http://individual.utoronto.ca/kia/).   Both of these are referenced 3. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279408/how-to-run-debug-multiple-java-programs-with-one-ant-buildfile-on-seperate-con).

I am still unable to follow how to move from creating an ant launcher as described in 2 to running it as a java program in RAD as explained in 1.   In link 3, the person mentioned that they were able to do it, but somehow I am not able to make the transition from ANT launcher I created using link in 2 to defining Main class and the VM parameters as described in 1.

Can someone explain how to do it?  I tried to add it as a comment to link in Question #3, but I couldn't add it as a comment, so creating a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about wasting resource here.  I wasn't able to get it to work, because I was putting the -f "build file " in location box instead of arguments box.  Once i fixed that, it is working now